Relation between minimal free resolution and free resolution
Let $R=k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ and $M$ be a $R-$module. Every free resolution of a module contains a minimal free resolution of module as direct summand.
My thoughts: A free resolution is said to be minimal if each module in resolution has minimum number of generators. So every free resolution has minimal free resolution as direct summand.
But I'm unable to prove the statement.
Another question is: Let F be minimal free resolution of M such that $F_{i}=\bigoplus_{j} R(-j)^{\beta_{ij}}$ and let G be free resolution with $G_{i}=\bigoplus_{j} R(-j)^{\gamma_{ij}}$. Then ${\gamma_{ij}}\geq {\beta_{ij}}$ for all $i,j$.
